# Reference or book on simulation of experimental design data in R

Tags: r, references, experiment-design, simulation

Can someone tell a reference and/or book that explain how to use *R* for simulation of experimental design data?

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what you mean by "simulation of experimental design data"? Are you looking after some function or R code that possibly generate random data for e.g., a RCBD or Latin square?

Comment: @chl: Yes, I'm looking some R codes to generate random data for experimental designs like CRD, RCBD, Latin and other design situations. Any idea. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Statistical models in S*, by Chambers and Hastie (Chapmann and Hall, 1991; or the so-called *White Book*), and to a lesser extent *Modern Applied Statistics with S*, by Venables and Ripley (Springer, 2002, 4th ed.), include some material about DoE and the analysis of common designs in S and R. Vikneswaran wrote [An R companion to "Experimental Design"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Vikneswaran-ED_companion.pdf), although it is not very complete (IMHO), but there are a lot other textbooks in the [Contributed](http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html) section on CRAN that might help you get started.

Apart from textbook, the CRAN Task View on [Design of Experiments (DoE) & Analysis of Experimental Data](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ExperimentalDesign.html) has some good packages that ease the creation and analysis of various experimental designs; I can think of [dae](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dae/index.html), [agricolae](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/agricolae/index.html), or [AlgDesign](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AlgDesign/index.html) (which comes with a nice [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AlgDesign/vignettes/AlgDesign.pdf)), to name a few.

Comment: Could you please refer me a book available in online for simulation study in R (not only for design of experiment,but also for basic learning which will develop strong basic background. )

Answer (score 4):

I have the feeling that pretty recent "**[Introduction to Scientific Programming and Scientific Simulation Using R](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420068725)**" by Owen Jones, Robert Maillardet, and Andrew Robinson (2009) could be what you are looking for.

There is also a very positive review for it [in the Journal of Statistical Software.](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v36/b04/paper).

Although this book is not specifically targeted at simulating experimental data it will probably get you in the direction you want to go.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of some code that I wrote for this purpose. The experimental design is: there are four levels of nitrogen and six replicates at each level. These data could be tested using a one-way ANOVA, but as the levels are continuous, I tested the fit of different curves.

```
set.seed(1)
library(nlme)
library(ggplot2)
### Below is a set of practice data 

## 1. four levels of Nitrogen:
##    0,1,4,10
N <- c(rep(0,6),rep(1,6),rep(4,6),rep(10,6))

## 2. variance 
s <- 2

## 3. Data simulated to provide examples of the
##    Various hypothesized responses of Y to N 

## 3.1 asymptotic incr Y = 10*N/(1+N) + 10
asym <- c(rnorm(6,10,s),rnorm(6,15,s),rnorm(6,18,s),rnorm(6,19,s))
## 3.2 Y = 0*N + 10 the Null model
m0 <- c(rnorm(24,10,s))
## 3.3 Y =0.2*N+10 a shallow slope
m1  <- c(rnorm(6,10,s),rnorm(6,10.2,s),rnorm(6,10.8,s),rnorm(6,12,s))
## 3.4 Y = 1*N + 10 a more steep slope
m4 <- c(rnorm(6,10,s),rnorm(6,14,s),rnorm(6,26,s),rnorm(6,50,s))
## 3.5 Y = 4*log10(N)+ 10 an log-linear response
lm4 <- c(rnorm(6,10,s),rnorm(6,12.4,s),rnorm(6,15.6,s),rnorm(6,18.2,s))
## 3.6 'Hump' with max at N=1 g m-2 yr 
hump <- c(rnorm(6,10,s),rnorm(6,20,s),rnorm(6,9,s),rnorm(6,8,s))

## A function to compare the fit of five models:

fn.BIC.lmnls <- function (x,y,shape){
  foo.null <- lm ( y~1)
  foo.poly1 <- lm(y~x)
  foo.poly2 <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))
  foo.poly3 <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3) )
  foo.mm <- nls ( y~ (a*x)/(b + x),start=list(a=1,b=1))
  bic <- BIC(foo.null,foo.poly1,foo.poly2,foo.poly3,foo.mm)
  print(bic)
  return(bic)
}

### now, plot data and print BIC values for each of the data sets
par(mfrow = c(3,2))
fn.BIC.lmnls    (N,m0,"Y = 0*N +10")
fn.BIC.lmnls    (N,m1,"Y = 0.2*N + 10")
fn.BIC.lmnls (N,m4,"Y = 1*N + 10") 
fn.BIC.lmnls (N,lm4,"Y = 0.4*log10(N) + 10")
fn.BIC.lmnls (N,asym,"Y = 10+10*N/(1+N)")#Y = 20*N/(5+N)
fn.BIC.lmnls (N,hump,"Y =  [10,20,9,8]")
```